# How to change D3js Gauge chart color, using update function?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using following chart http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6

I just want to update the color of gauge without changing the value

I've tried using following:

```
d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove(); 
gauge1 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge1", 17, configNew1); 
gauge2 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge2", 60, configNew2)
```

but this remove the existing chart and replace it with new.

Then I reach to another D3js Function which is "Update"? from which I can update the value of the chart, 
I tried to update the color using

```
gauge1.update.config1.circleColor("#ff0000")
```

but no luck.

I'm just assuming that this function might work but not sure

Comment: Can you provide some more information? What have you tried so far? For example to update the color of the circle for the first Gauge you siply change `config1.circleColor = "#FF7777";` to the color that you want.

Comment: I've tried using following:

d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove(); 
gauge1 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge1", 17, configNew1);
gauge2 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge2", 60, configNew2)

but this remove the existing chart and replace it with new.

Then I reach to another D3js Function which is "Update"?
from which I can update the value of the chart, I tried to update the color using "gauge1.update.config1.circleColor("#ff0000")" but no luck.

I'm just assuming that this function might work but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The update function does currently only take a new value, so all you can do to it is to change the value. To also be able to change the style/color/config you need to update it.

**Step1**, update the `update`-function so it also takes a new config:

```
this.update = function(value,config){
```

**Step2**, update the transition for the text, and add new transition for the circle/wave so that they also update the color:

```
text1.transition()
    .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
    .tween("text", textTween)
    .style("fill", config.textColor)
text2.transition()
    .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
    .tween("text", textTween)
    .style("fill", config.waveTextColor);
fillCircleGroup.select('circle').transition()
    .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
    .style("fill", config.waveColor);
gaugeGroup.select('path').transition()
    .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
    .style("fill", config.circleColor);
```

This is all that is needed, and you can now call

```
gauge1.update(NewValue(),newConfig)
```

**Example:** Update all the colors of gauge

```
//Generate four random colors
var rndColor1 = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
var rndColor2 = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
var rndColor3 = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
var rndColor4 = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

//Generate a new config and update the colors
var newConfig = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
newConfig.textColor = rndColor1;
newConfig.waveTextColor = rndColor2;
newConfig.circleColor = rndColor3;
newConfig.waveColor = rndColor4;

//Call the update-function, wich now also takes a new config
gauge2.update(NewValue(),newConfig);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/15h0fxn7/) is a fiddle where gague2 is updated each second with a random color